# react-draggable Unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, draggable

Whenever I refresh my page after inserting the Draggable component, my page stops rendering and the HTML root element no longer has any children. I've tried putting it in the primary App component and still get the same error below in the console.

```
import React from 'react'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import './Styles.css';

function Card() {
  
  return (
    <Draggable>
      <div className='SCard'>
        <div>Text</div>
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  )
}

export default Card
```

```
react-dom.development.js:4303 Uncaught Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
    at findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath (react-dom.development.js:4303:1)
    at findCurrentHostFiber (react-dom.development.js:4465:1)
    at findHostInstanceWithWarning (react-dom.development.js:25389:1)
    at Object.findDOMNode (react-dom.development.js:26067:1)
    at DraggableCore.findDOMNode (DraggableCore.js:389:1)
    at DraggableCore.componentDidMount (DraggableCore.js:352:1)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23305:1)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:1)
findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath @ react-dom.development.js:4303
findCurrentHostFiber @ react-dom.development.js:4465
findHostInstanceWithWarning @ react-dom.development.js:25389
findDOMNode @ react-dom.development.js:26067
findDOMNode @ DraggableCore.js:389
componentDidMount @ DraggableCore.js:352
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23305
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <DraggableCore> component:

    at DraggableCore (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72974:5)
    at Draggable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72264:5)
    at StressCard
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Surprisingly, I haven't found anyone else reporting this problem as it just works upon implementation. Any help is appreciated (please be very specific as I'm quite new to web dev), thanks!